# Predicate Logic Translation to English

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let the domain of discourse be all people on Facebook. You should use only the predicate Friend(x, y),
which says that x and y are friends, and the predicates x = y and x $\neq$ y, which say whether or not x and y are
the same persons. You may assume that friendship is a symmetric relationship, so Friend(x, y) and Friend(y, x)
are the same. You can use constants to refer to specific people such as the “Bob” in the next example.

I am trying to translate the statement: "Two people have Bob as a mutual friend only if they are also friends"

I have come up with the following translation: ∀x(x $\neq$ Bob ^ Friend(x,Bob) ^ ∀y((y $\neq$ Bob)^ Friend(y, Bob) --> Friend(x,Bob) ^ Friend(y,Bob))). From the way I understand this, two people who are friends with Bob means that then they are mutual friends with Bob (statements after implication).

Is this the correct interpretation? Additionally, how would something like this be negated? I've tried utilizing DeMorgan's laws for Quatifiers but just got more and more confused.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use \land for $\land$ instead of ^.... and \lor for $\lor$.

Comment: You just need common sense to negate it. In that case you'd have two distinct people both of which are friends with Bob but who are not themselves friends.

Comment: Mate you can just delete the question. Why're you writing "Deleted Question" everywhere ?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you mean by "They". @Sanjay Patel can just delete the question himself. There must be an option to delete at the bottom of the q.

Comment: I don't think thats the case. I have a question in which one of the answers has 91 upvotes. And I have an option to delete. Just tried it.

Comment: I said "one of the answers" ..

Comment: @JamesA So it lets you delete the question. But it's gonna wait for a while before the deletion happens. This convo has become so irrelevant to the question asked XD

Answer (score 3):

I'd say (using just $F$ for friend and $b$ for Bob):
$\forall x,y: \left( (x \neq  y) \land F(x,b) \land F(y,b)\right) \to F(x,y)$

The first clause just says that $x,$ are distinct people having Bob as a friend, and then follows the necessary conclusion: they must already be friends of each other... (the "only if").

Your statement translation doesn't state "they are also friends", but reaffirms what you already know: that they're friends with Bob. So I'm pretty sure that's wrong. Also, the quantifiers are weirdly placed IMO. The way I'm doing it I state a "law" over the whole domain, which I think is intended.